# Using OAuth 1.0 encoded requests for external web service calls Error: signature_invalid

Tags: apex, rest-api, oauth

Please help me.

I have a  salesforce requirement that necessitates a callout from Apex to an external web service that receives signed OAuth responses.

I am getting oAuth_token successfully.
But after that when I am trying to get data using that oAuth_token I am getting error 'signature_invalid'.

Check getAccData method from code as below.

```
    global class OAuthToken
    {
        private OAuthService__c service;
        private String token;
        private String tokenSecret;
        private Boolean isAccess = false;
        private String verifier;
        private String nonce;
        private String timestamp;
        private String signature;
        private String consumerKey;
        private String consumerSecret;    
        private Map<String,String> parameters = new Map<String,String>();    
        public String message { get; set; }
        public String callbackUrl {get; set; }
        public void setConsumerKey(String value) { consumerKey = value; }
        public void setConsumerSecret(String value) { consumerSecret = value; }

        public String newAuthorization(String serviceName)
        {        
            service = [SELECT request_token_url__c, access_token_url__c, consumer_key__c,consumer_secret__c, authorization_url__c,
                              (select token__c, secret__c, isAccess__c FROM tokens__r WHERE owner__c=:UserInfo.getUserId() ) 
                              FROM OAuthService__c WHERE name = :serviceName];

            if(service==null)
             {
                System.debug('Couldn\'t find Oauth Service '+serviceName);
                message = 'Service '+serviceName+' was not found in the local configuration';
                return null;
             }

             if(callbackUrl==null) 
             { 
                if(ApexPages.currentPage()==null || ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')==null) {
                    message = 'No callback page was set and it couldn\'t be generated from Apex context';
                    System.debug(message);
                    return null;
                }

                callbackUrl = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('https://'+ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')+
                                                     Page.CompleteAuth.getUrl(),'UTF-8');
             }

            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setEndpoint('https://www.gliffy.com/api/1.0/accounts/5023581/users/nileshbhd5@gmail.com/oauth_token.xml?action=create&description=createuser');//service.request_token_url__c        
            req.setTimeout(12000);
            System.debug('Request body set to: '+req.getBody());
            consumerKey = service.consumer_key__c;
            consumerSecret = service.consumer_secret__c;
            sign(req);
            HttpResponse res = null;        
            res = h.send(req);    
            String XMLString = res.getBody();
            parseXML(XMLString); 

            System.debug('Response from request token request: ('+res.getStatusCode()+')'+res.getBody());
            if(res.getStatusCode()>299) {
                message = 'Failed getting a request token. HTTP Code = '+res.getStatusCode()+
                          '. Message: '+res.getStatus()+'. Response Body: '+res.getBody();
                return null;
            }
            String resParams = serviceName == 'test1234' ?'oauth_token=token&oauth_token_secret=token_secret' : res.getBody();
            Map<String,String> rp = getUrlParams(resParams);
            OAuth_Token__c t = new OAuth_Token__c();
            t.owner__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
            t.OAuth_Service__c = service.id;
            t.token__c = token;
            t.secret__c = tokenSecret;
            t.isAccess__c = false;
            delete service.tokens__r;
            insert t;

            System.debug('Got request token: '+t.token__c+'('+rp.get('oauth_token')+')');

            if(service.authorization_url__c.contains('?')) {
            string getAccountURL = 'https://www.gliffy.com/api/1.0/accounts/5023581/users.xml?action=get'+'&oauth_token='+token;
                return getAccountURL;
            } else {
                return service.authorization_url__c+'?oauth_token='+EncodingUtil.urlDecode(t.token__c,'UTF-8')+'&oauth_consumer_key='+service.consumer_key__c;
            }
        }


         public String getAccData(String authUrlName)
         {
           service = [SELECT request_token_url__c, access_token_url__c, consumer_key__c,consumer_secret__c, authorization_url__c,
                              (select token__c, secret__c, isAccess__c FROM tokens__r WHERE owner__c=:UserInfo.getUserId() ) 
                              FROM OAuthService__c WHERE name = :'Gliffy'];
          if(service==null)
             {
                System.debug('Couldn\'t find Oauth Service '+'Gliffy');
                message = 'Service '+'Gliffy'+' was not found in the local configuration';
                return null;
             }

           if(callbackUrl==null) 
             { 
                if(ApexPages.currentPage()==null || ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')==null) {
                    message = 'No callback page was set and it couldn\'t be generated from Apex context';
                    System.debug(message);
                    return null;
                }

                callbackUrl = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('https://'+ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')+
                                                     Page.CompleteAuth.getUrl(),'UTF-8');
             }

            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setEndpoint(authUrlName);
            req.setTimeout(12000);
            consumerKey = service.consumer_key__c;
            consumerSecret = service.consumer_secret__c;
            sign(req);
            HttpResponse res = null;
            res = h.send(req);
            String XMLString = res.getBody();
            system.debug('Accountdata String:'+XMLString );
            return XMLString;
         }

        private void refreshParameters() 
        {
            parameters.clear();
            parameters.put('oauth_consumer_key',consumerKey);
            if(token!=null) {
                parameters.put('oauth_token',token);
            }
            if(verifier!=null) {
                parameters.put('oauth_verifier',verifier);
            }
            parameters.put('oauth_signature_method','HMAC-SHA1');
            parameters.put('oauth_timestamp',timestamp);
            parameters.put('oauth_nonce',nonce);
            parameters.put('oauth_callback',callbackUrl);
        }

        public void sign(HttpRequest req) 
        {

            nonce = String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomLong());
            timestamp = String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime()/1000);
            refreshParameters();        
            String s = createBaseString(parameters, req);        

            Blob sig = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(s), 
                           Blob.valueOf(consumerSecret+'&'+
                                        (tokenSecret!=null ? tokenSecret : '')));
            signature = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64encode(sig), 'UTF-8');
            System.debug('Signature: '+signature);

            String header = 'OAuth ';
            for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
                header = header + key + '="'+parameters.get(key)+'", ';
            }
            header = header + 'oauth_signature="'+signature+'"';
            System.debug('Authorization: '+header);
            req.setHeader('Authorization',header);
        }

      private String createBaseString(Map<String,String> oauthParams,HttpRequest req) 
        {
            Map<String,String> p = oauthParams.clone();
            if(req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase('post') && req.getBody()!=null && 
               req.getHeader('Content-Type')=='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
               {
                p.putAll(getUrlParams(req.getBody()));
            }
            String host = req.getEndpoint();
            Integer n = host.indexOf('?');
            if(n>-1) {
                p.putAll(getUrlParams(host.substring(n+1)));
                host = host.substring(0,n);
            }
            List<String> keys = new List<String>();
            keys.addAll(p.keySet());
            keys.sort();
            String s = keys.get(0)+'='+p.get(keys.get(0));
            for(Integer i=1;i<keys.size();i++) {
                s = s + '&' + keys.get(i)+'='+p.get(keys.get(i));
            }

            return req.getMethod().toUpperCase()+ '&' + 
                EncodingUtil.urlEncode(host, 'UTF-8') + '&' +
                EncodingUtil.urlEncode(s, 'UTF-8');
        }

      private Map<String,String> getUrlParams(String value) 
        {
            Map<String,String> res = new Map<String,String>();
            if(value==null || value=='')
            {
                return res;
            }
            for(String s : value.split('&')) 
            {
                System.debug('getUrlParams: '+s);
                List<String> kv = s.split('=');
                if(kv.size()>1) {              
                  String encName = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(kv[0], 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8').replace('+','%20');
                  String encValue = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(kv[1], 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8').replace('+','%20');
                  System.debug('getUrlParams:  -> '+encName+','+encValue);
                  res.put(encName,encValue);
                }
            }
            return res;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you log the values for nonce, timestamp and other parameters and provide those as part of your post above?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, 
Thanks for reply.
Check values as below.
oauth_consumer_key="8890f31c-b358-46c1-ba4e-77cf6ef73b77", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
oauth_timestamp="1451881241", 
oauth_nonce="-4542704040566133557", 
oauth_callback="https%3A%2F%2Fc.ap2.visual.force.com%2Fapex%2Fcompleteauth", 
oauth_signature="QkgQkXmlXeWhWke0gzHLkDw4VEg%3D"

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Gliffy's (no longer supported) REST API. Your best way forward is to look at their [client libraries](https://www.gliffy.com/products/online/api/client-libraries/) and check that the OAuth signing algorithms match, and that the same input generates the same output.